# How to use law of sines in code

Tags: java, math, libgdx, box2d

I have a question concercing calculating a velocity x and y based on the diagonal side. Of a triangle. Check the following drawing

[image]

In this case I know all the angle of each corner and I know A it is always 600.

I have started searching and came across the law of sines, I think I should use this but I can't figure out how to use it in Java.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I got so far

```
        Vector2 pos = mBall.getPosition();
    double angleA = Math.atan2(target.x - pos.x, target.y - pos.y) * 180.0d / Math.PI;
    double angleB = 90.0f;
    double angleC = 180f - (angleA + angleB);
    double sideA = MAXIMUM_VELOCITY;
    double lawofsines = sideA / Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleA));
```

Comment: Value of sine is ≤ 1. Length of _B_ ≤ length of _A_. Clearly `B = A * sin(a)` and `C = A * sin(c)`; noticing that _c = 90º - a_, also `C = A * cos(a)`.

Comment: @9000: You should be very careful when you write a formula after "Clearly".

Comment: You'll need to better define your problem, because it isn't clear at all right now. Please just state what the inputs are, and what the expected output is. No Java code, no law of sines, ... Right now, you calculate an angle from `x,y` coordinates, and you try to calculate those coordinates from the corresponding angle.

Comment: @EricDuminil, Indeed, and thanks for noticing; a direct correction would be appreciated even more.

Comment: ^^^^ Of course, `B` and `C` got swapped in my comment; `C = A * sin(a)`.

Comment: @9000 can comments be edited by others ? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @EricDuminil: No; comments cannot be even edited by authors after some time. This is why I'm not fixing mine: I can't.

Comment: @9000 so I don't understand what you mean with direct correction. You can delete wrong comments, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `atan2` wrong. The calling convention is modeled after the one for the arcus tangent, `atan(dy/dx)` to be

```
atan2(dy, dx)
```

But as far as can be seen from the code, you do not need to calculate the angels as the unit direction to the target is sufficient,

```
dx = target.x-pos.x
dy = target.y-pos.y

ds = Math.hypot(dx,dy)

vel.x = MAXIMUM_VELOCITY * (dx/ds)
vel.y = MAXIMUM_VELOCITY * (dy/ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the law of sines.  Since in a normal coordinate system the X and Y dimensions are by definition perpendicular you can just use:

```
X = A*Cos(a) where a is the angle and A is the hypotenuse 
Y = A*Sin(a)
```

This comes from the properties of a [`Right Triangle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle).

Comment: Problem is : `X` and `Y` are already known. I honestly don't know what OP wants.